# Replacing mystery outdoor faucet

Tags: plumbing, outdoorfaucet

I am anxious to replace an outdoor faucet but sick of it leaking and splashing back on turning on and off.

There’s mystery holes above where the hoses connect that causes the leaking.

Very confusing... and the amount of paint on it is confusing me on what I can unthread and replace.

Very subtle I can make out the number 76-100 8 ?

Any intel on replacement parts or procedures appreciated. There’s not much pipe sticking out so I’m hoping to avoid pipe cutting and soldering a new connection.

[image: side pic of faucet]

[image: other side]

[image: top view]

[image: i can see part number 76-100]

[video](https://youtu.be/s7KXaWsG6sk)

Comment: Seems like where the hose connects, is a reducing thread adapter.  This should be able to be removed from the faucet.  Leak seems like either on adapter side or the plastic hose connector.  One or both not sealing well together.

Comment: Nothing mysterious about a hose vacuum breaker, evidently slightly malfunctioning. The valve is probably soldered in place, that's a typical "threads outside, solder inside" fitting, so "unthreading it" is just going to twist the pipe it's soldered to.

Comment: @paulywill do you ever get overnight frosts?  If so, Harper's suggestion of a sillcock will help.  If you live in the balmy tropical areas of the world, then your pipes outside won't freeze and you can just replace/service the tap fitting itself.

Answer (score 5):

### Yes, faucets *are* serviceable.

Soak it in Kroil or PB Blaster, then clean it up with a hand wirebrush.  At that point, the seams between metal pieces should be more visible.  Then, call a decent handyman versed in plumbing to take it apart and replace the stem packing and any washers.

A *highly competent* hardware store will have that stuff in stock.  By which I mean a local family-owned hardware store that's been there for 100 years type of deal.

It's true that they make cheap Chinese faucets these days that are 100% unserviceable, but this one appears to be old, and with a logo on it.  So I suspect it is serviceable.

If the unit is NOT serviceable, then the valve must be replaced from the *interior* of the house.  The end of the valve isn't where you think it is.

### Consider a *sillcock*

I mistook this for a sillcock, because the faucet is not at an angle like a typical faucet, but square-on to the pipe (so the shaft can go down the pipe).

The sillcock is actually quite long and goes all the way into the interior of the house, where it's warm. The actual water valve is there.   The purpose is to protect the valve from freeze damage.   It will self-drain and is *freeze-proof, if nothing is attached to it*.

Sillcocks have certain rules about not connecting things to them indefinitely.  Those can damage sillcocks.  That's also why I thought you were having the problem I thought you were having.
[image]

Comment: Are you really sure it's a sillcock? Why would a sillcock have the male threads on the pipe end?

Comment: That's is clearly NOT a sillcock, from the location of the threaded/solder connection alone. It's a simple boiler drain or hose bibb, with an added vacuum breaker that's malfunctioning.

Comment: Ok, I assumed it was a sillcock of unusual construction.  It *should be* a sillcock though.

Answer (score 1):

> replacement parts

No you will not find replacement parts for a simple hose faucet

> hoping to avoid pipe cutting and soldering

Your hopes are dashed- the faucet is soldered on and to replace it you will need to either un-solder it or cut the 1/2" copper pipe. I would un-solder it (because I would not want the pipe to be any shorter than it is already) and solder a male thread adapter on, to which I would then be able to attach a new female-threaded hose faucet.